# Using asType with Mixin annotation

Tags: dynamic, groovy, metaprogramming, categories, mixins

I'd like write a custom type conversion [Category](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Category+and+Mixin+transformations) in Groovy. The goal is to assign the values of a `Map` to the fields of a Groovy bean. In the future there will be different response types. The values of of the `Map` are always of type `String` but will have to be converted into a different data type. To make this work I created a Category class that implements a method named `asType`. This is a simplified example of my code:

```
class MapCategory {
    static Object asType(Map self, Class clazz) {
        if(clazz == Response) {
            Response response = new Response()

            self.each { key, value ->
                response.setProperty(key, value)
            }

            return response
        }

        DefaultGroovyMethods.asType(self, clazz)
    }
}

class Response {
    String result
    String message
}
```

This works just fine when when I apply the category using the `use` keyword.

```
use(MapCategory) {
    println [result: 'OK', message: 'Success'] as Response
}
```

However, when I try to use the `@Mixin` annotation instead it doesn't seem to work correctly. I get the correct response type but all fields are `null`.

```
@Mixin(MapCategory)
class MyClass {
    def printResponse() {
        println [result: 'OK', message: 'Success'] as Response    
    }
}
```

Does anybody know why it doesn't work correctly using the annotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixins don't work that way.  You are trying to mix in the method for `Map` into your `MyClass` object.  The mixin would only work if `MyClass` extended `Map`.

Instead, you want to use the `use` keyword like normal, and just use your category as a category.

Alternatively, you might not need it at all.  Did you know that you can, by default, convert any map into any GroovyBean without extra code?  Just use the map-based constructor, like so:

```
@groovy.transform.Canonical // Groovy 1.8, just added for automatic toString method
class Response {
    String result
    String message
}

println new Response([result: 'OK', message: 'Success'])
println([result: 'bad', message: 'blah'] as Response)
```

Notice, automatic Map conversion works both ways.  It's a built-in feature of Groovy.

Of course, if you need something more complex than just assigning bean properties, this won't help.

*Note: I'd give you a link, but the Groovy website appears to be broken, and I can't find code examples.  :-(*

**EDIT: Another Suggestion**

Instead of using a Category at all, why don't you let the bean itself handle it:

```
@groovy.transform.Canonical
class Response {
    String result
    String message
    int num

    public void setNum(String num) {
       this.num = Integer.parseInt(num) 
    }
}

def map = [result: 'OK', message: 'Success', num: '35' ]

println map as Response
```

Comment: I know about passing a `Map` to a Groovy Bean. My example code is simplified. The actual bean has other data types as well like `Integer` and `Boolean`. However, my `Map` only holds `Strings` in the beginning. In my Category I would convert it to the correct data type.

Comment: OK, well, like I said at the top, then use `use` instead.  Alternatively, I've updated it with another suggestion.

Comment: Oops, forgot `this.` in front of the assignment.  Second example should work now.

Comment: I think I'll just set the fields manually instead of using a Category.